# why !important doesn't work in CSS in my code

Tags: html, css

here I have two menu.my problem is I can't change the text color of vertical menu. I use 'color: red !important' in list-item class but it did't work.I think I should change  '.dropbtn ,li a ' but I don't know how to change it.(I want to define 2 different color)
and it is complete  code:
http://jsfiddle.net/cudn8es7/63/

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  direction: rtl;
  font-family: "tahoma";
}

html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

u1{
  list-style: none;
}

.firstmenu {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: rgba(20,30,250,0.5);
  font-family: "B Nazanin";
  direction: rtl;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.firstmenu  a:hover {
  background-color: aqua;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}
.firstmenu li {
  float: right;

}
.dropbtn ,li a {
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  direction: rtl;
  transition: all 1s;
}
li.dropdown {
  display: inline-block;
}
.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: right;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

.menu {
  width: 12%;
  float: right;
  direction: rtl;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "B Nazanin";
  margin-top: 30px;
  color: red;
}

.list-item{
  box-shadow:-5px 4px 3px 1px gray ;
  background-color: deepskyblue;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: red !important;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px 0px 0px 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  transition: transform 1s;
}

.menu li:hover{
  transform: scalex(1.4);
  transition: all 0.5s;
  background-color: blue;
  color: pink !important;
}

a:active{
  color:yellow;
}

#banner{
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  z-index: -1 ;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>دومین صفحه وب من</title>
</head>
<body>
 
<ul class="firstmenu">

    <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropbtn">menu</a>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
            <a href="#">home</a>
            <a href="#exprience">exprience</a>
            <a href="#education">education</a>
            <a href="#cv">CV</a>
            <a href="#contact">contact</a>
        </div>
    </li>

    <li><a href="#exprience1">exprience</a></li>
 
    <li><a href="#education1">education</a></li>
 
    <li><a href="#CV1">CV</a></li>
  
    <li><a href="#contact1">contact</a></li>
  
</ul>

  <img src="https://splashingpaint.files.wordpress.com/2018/03/corella-remnants.jpg"  id="banner">


<div id="wrapper">
 
        
         <div class="menu">
        <ul>
            <li class="list-item">
                <a href="#exprience">exprience</a>
            </li>
            <li class="list-item">
                <a href="#education">education</a>
            </li>
            <li class="list-item">
                <a href="#cv">CV</a>
            </li>
            <li class="list-item">
                <a href="#contact">contact</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
        
  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: do you have anywhere else !important in your css, i only added color: red; on .dropdown, li a .... here is screenshot __________ http://prntscr.com/kauen5

Comment: The code you put in the question (a) does not include `!important` and (b) does not include any HTML.

Comment: First thing first it's IMPORTANT not to use `!important` for things like this. Second, try to clear up your CSS and maybe it will work. Third try to read something about CSS Specificity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to Add This class

```
#wrapper > div > ul > li > a {
  color:red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this and no need to add  `!important` in `.menu li:hover`

```
.menu li:hover a{
  color: pink;
}
```

Update jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/cudn8es7/68/)

Answer (score 0):

```
  .menu ul li a{
  color:red!important;
}
```

**This is the solution , But ill recommend you to don't use `!important` , coz it is not consider as good programming practise and try to use class based sections  , It will help you desiring your web page**

Answer (score -1):

You can just write the css for styling vertical menu anchor tags. There is no need of !important to use it over here.

```
.menu li a {color: red;}
```

Comment: 2 different colors for what?